# Android HTTP Basic Authentication not adding on server

Tags: android, http-headers

I am using basic HTTP authorization for web service call and it works perfectly alright on my local machine but same code is not working on hosted server.It does not add the Authorization header at all.Here is the android code i am using,

```
URL objurl = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection httpconn =    (HttpURLConnection)objurl.openConnection();

httpconn.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpconn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
       "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpconn.setRequestProperty( "Accept", "*/*" );     

httpconn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + 
           Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));  


String str_tm= "username:password";

byte[] encoded = Base64.encode(str_tm.getBytes("CP1252"), Base64.NO_WRAP);
String str = new String(encoded, "CP1252");

    httpconn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "basic " + str);

httpconn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  

httpconn.setUseCaches (false);
httpconn.setDoInput(true);
httpconn.setDoOutput(true);

//Send request
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
        httpconn.getOutputStream ());
wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
wr.flush ();
wr.close ();
```

The response headers from server is machine are:

```
"headers":
   { "Accept-Encoding":"gzip",
   "Connection":"close",
   "Host":"restaulogy.com",
   "User-Agent":"Dalvik\/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1; sdk_phone_armv7 Build\/LKY45)",
   "Content-Language":"en-US","Content-Length":"30",
   "Accept":"*\/*",
   "Content-Type":"application\/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  }
```

And request headers from my local machine are:

```
"headers":
{
"Content-Type":"application\/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"Accept":"*\/*",
"Content-Length":"30",
"Authorization":"basic NjAyMjM3MTEzMTprcjJwTzJrTHorMFcvSGYwd3VWZFRNRzVzMGd5TXpCaE5USXdNekZs",
"Content-Language":"en-US",
"User-Agent":"Dalvik\/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1; sdk_phone_armv7 Build\/LKY45)",
"Host":"192.168.1.112",
"Connection":"Keep-Alive",
"Accept-Encoding":"gzip"
}
```

Looking at the response "Authorization" header is missing and "Connection":"close".Can some one help me.Urgent.

Comment: Did you try using `addRequestProperty()` instead of `.setRequestProperty("Authorization"...)`?

Comment: tried that but no luck